# Are tag-only edits intentionally disallowed?

Tags: support, bug, tags, retagging, editing

Today, I tried to add the [first-person-pronouns](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/first-person-pronouns) tag to [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/39514/9212), but was unable to save due to not changing at least 6 characters within the post itself:

[image]

In the past (e.g. [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/revisions/31057/3) or [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/revisions/31097/3)), I've been able to make tag-only edits without problems; so this seems to have been changed at some point.

My question is: Are tag-only edits now *intentionally* prevented (i.e. discouraged), or is this a bug of some sort?

**UPDATE:** I was able to make a tag-only edit to [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/10367), so either way it looks like this is a bug.

Comment: People have solved this problem simply by trying again later: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4478/editing-tags-not-allowed-because-not-6-characters could you try again and tell us if the problem persists?

Comment: @Earthliŋ I've tried a few times now, but it doesn't seem to be working. Perhaps I will try again after a decent pause, say in an hour or so.

Comment: Also see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234345/edit-must-be-at-least-6-characters-but-i-am-retagging This might be a bug indeed.

Comment: Just to confirm: I've tried to make this same edit a few times over the last few hours, and am still unable to do so.

Comment: Sorry, I think my understanding was wrong. Good luck.